# Ruby Daemons Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, daemons

I installed the ruby gem Daemons.  To make sure it was working I created a script that would print to a file every 5 seconds. I then created another file to run the script using the trivial example they give you in the readme located at http://daemons.rubyforge.org/ .  I require both rubygems and daemons.  Then I type 'ruby mycontrol.rb start'.  The example they use has some type of message saying       '(myserver.rb is now running in the background)', I don't see that, but I don't get any errors. If I do a 'ps -u myusername' I see that the filed to be daemonized is listed in the processes, but doesn't appear to be running as nothing is getting written to the file.

Here is my source:

```
# this is mycontrol.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run(daemon.rb)
```

and...

```
# this is daemon.rb

loop do 
 open('file.out', 'w') do |f|
  f.puts 'hello everybody'
 end
 sleep(3)
end
```

Does anything I'm doing jump out at you as being wrong?

Thanks, 
Tony

Comment: Please could you reformat your code (indent it by 4 spaces) to make it more readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried your example and it works for me (Ruby 1.8.6 on Linux with Daemons version 1.0.10). However, you may be encountering the following issues:

- I found that the daemonized process (`daemon.rb`) was being started with a current working directory of `/`. This was not the current directory when running `mycontrol.rb` or the directory that contained `daemon.rb`. Running as a non-root user meant that my process didn't have permission to write the file. I changed the filename to `/tmp/file.out` and the file was created with the expected content.
- You are opening `file.out` in write-only (`'w'`) mode. This means that it will be truncated and rewritten every 3 seconds. If you open the file in append (`'a'`) mode you will see an additional `hello everybody` line written to the file every 3 seconds.

I don't see the 'is now running in the background' messages either. I assume this is included in the documentation to illustrate what should have happened rather than to indicate the output.